# Custom area legend image not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I'm trying to use the result from a `fill between` as a legend entry, but I can't get it to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot[name path = upper, draw = none] {5 + rand};
            \addplot[name path = lower, draw = none] {-5 + rand};
            \addplot[black!10, area legend] fill between[of = upper and lower];
            \addlegendentry{My interval}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

with a line in the legend image instead of the rectangle I expected from using `area legend` in the options to `\addplot`.

I tried providing a legend image manually using

```
\addlegendimage{\draw[fill = black!10] (0cm, -0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm, 0.1cm)}
```

but that did nothing. (The `\draw` code is inspired by Section 4.9.5 in the pgfplots manual and is supposed to be the default appearance of a `area legend` entry.)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Adding `area legend` to the axis option gets me halfway there, but the fill is still not right.

[image]

Comment: You've got me baffled. The `pgfplots` manual shows an example of this "just working" on p. 382 (v1.12) with no special handling.

Comment: The first \addlegendentry refers to the first \addplot, the second \addlegendentry refers to the second \addplot, and so on.  It doesn't matter where they are relative to each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment by John Kormylo put me on the right track. The key is to make the legend refer to the third plot only by issuing `forget plot` to the two previous ones. The following works:

```
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[name path = upper, draw = none, forget plot] {5 + rand};
    \addplot[name path = lower, draw = none, forget plot] {-5 + rand};
    \addplot[fill = black!10, area legend] fill between[of = upper and lower];
    \addlegendentry{My interval}
\end{axis}
```

[image]