# Dual axis Plot problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, floats

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}  % table scale


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=.75\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        symbolic x coords={40,60,80,100,120},
        xtick=data,
        legend columns=-1,
        legend style={draw=none},
        legend to name=named,
    }

    \begin{axis}[
    axis y line*=left,
    xlabel=x-axis,
    ylabel=y-axis 1,
    ybar stacked, ymin=0,
    bar width=7mm, 
    legend entries={a,b},
    ]
    \addplot [fill=blue] coordinates {
        ({40},15)
        ({60},25)
        ({80},35)
        ({100},15)
        ({120},10)
    };
    \addplot [fill=red] coordinates {
        ({40},10)
        ({60},35)
        ({80},30)
        ({100},25)
        ({120},10)
    };
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[
    axis y line*=right,
    ylabel=y-axis 2, legend entries={time},
    ]


    \addplot[smooth,mark=*,black]
    coordinates{
        ({40},15)
        ({60},25)
        ({80},35)
        ({100},15)
        ({120},10)
    };
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\\
Sample: \ref{named}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Problems:

1. y-axis 2 label not appearing properly (appears left).
2. Legends not showing for stacked plots.
3. The text "Sample" and the legend seems to not appearing horizontally in the same line.

Comment: Possible duplicat: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199003/124842

Comment: I have created MWE from that link, for using my purpose. But not able to solve. Legend would be outside. Why Y axis-2 appearing on left side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is a combination of [@cfr answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199003/124842) and [@soapygopher answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246728/124842). The double text could be removed, by adding only one axis label. The legend position is defined with `legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north}` for both axis enviroments.

Here is the updated answer, because of question 3. You could add some text with inserting an extra column `legend columns=4` instead of `legend columns=3` with `legend style` you could do some format changes like `text width`. To add the extra text/titel use `\addlegendimage{empty legend}` and 
`\addlegendentry{\textbf{Sample:}}`. To add the second ylabel on the right side use `ylabel=y-axis 2, ylabel near ticks, yticklabel pos=right,` instead of `axis y line*=right,`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}  % table scale


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        symbolic x coords={40,60,80,100,120},
        xtick=data,
        legend columns=4,
        legend style={
                    /tikz/every even column/.append style={text width=1.4cm}
                        },
    }

    \begin{axis}[
    axis y line*=left,
    xlabel=x-axis 1,
    ylabel=y-axis 1,
    ybar stacked, ymin=0,
    bar width=7mm, legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north}
    ]

    \addplot [fill=blue,draw=none,area legend] coordinates {
        ({40},15)
        ({60},25)
        ({80},35)
        ({100},15)
        ({120},10)
    };\label{plot_one}
\addlegendentry{plot 1}
    \addplot [fill=red,draw=none,area legend] coordinates {
        ({40},10)
        ({60},35)
        ({80},30)
        ({100},25)
        ({120},10)
    };\label{plot_two}
\addlegendentry{plot 2}
    \end{axis}

 \begin{axis}[
    ylabel=y-axis 2, ylabel near ticks, yticklabel pos=right,legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north},
    ]
\addlegendimage{empty legend}
\addlegendentry{\hspace*{0cm}\textbf{Sample:}}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_one}\addlegendentry{plot 1}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_two}\addlegendentry{plot 2}
    \addplot[smooth,mark=*,black]
    coordinates{
        ({40},15)
        ({60},25)
        ({80},35)
        ({100},15)
        ({120},10)
    };
    \addlegendentry{plot 3}
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with 2x `\begin{axis}[...,ymin=0,ymax=70, ...]` you get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the ans. I updated some 1 extra requirement. Moreover, axis titles are required. [link] (https://www.overleaf.com/13996730spkbxmgbzjkh#/54278642/)

Comment: @Mr.EU : Do you want to add the word "Sample" to the legend? Related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2332/124842, but horizontal? -Then you could add `legend style={
                    /tikz/every even column/.append style={text width=1.4cm}
                        },` to `pgfplotsset` , `legend columns=4,` instead of `legend columns=4,` and `\addlegendimage{empty legend}
\addlegendentry{\hspace*{0cm}\textbf{Sample:}}` before your first legen entry.

Comment: thanks, can you please get the axis problem solve?

Comment: great. Thanks. only "Y axis 2" Title is required in right side. Also what causes it overlapping?

Comment: Do you want the label Y axis 2 on the right side? SO add: ` \begin{axis}[
    ylabel=y-axis 2, ylabel near ticks, yticklabel pos=right,legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north},
    ]` i will update my answer.

Comment: If both Y-Axis should have the same scaling use `,ymin=0,ymax=70,` for both axis[].